# Python: error during generation of XML file from python dictionary

Tags: installation, python, python-2.7, xml

```
ImportError: No module named elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter
```

The code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 

root = ET.Element("root") 
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc") 
field1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field1") 
field1.set("name", "blah") 
field1.text = "some value1" 
field2 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field2") 
field2.set("name", "asdfasd") 
field2.text = "some vlaue2" 
tree = ET.ElementTree(root) 
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: that was one of the file i found on net, I'm just trying to execute it, errors are coming as mentioned earlier..

Comment: In my ubuntu 12.04 everything works correctly

Comment: I'm currently using 12.0.4

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/xml`?

Comment: Hmm works like a charme here? Are you sure that the elementtree module is installed? I have Python 2.7.3.

Comment: How have you named your script? It could be important (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073033/python-2-5-4-importerror-no-module-named-etree-elementtree)

Comment: I don't have problems with 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04.  As a workaround, try `sudo pip install elementtree`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493629/importerror-no-module-named-elementtree-simplexmlwriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Have you named your script: `xml.py`? Change it and it should work.

As a workaround, you could use `etree` in the lxml package. If you don't have `lxml` installed, type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

And for the modified version of your program:

```
import lxml.etree as ET 

root = ET.Element("root") 
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc") 
field1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field1") 
field1.set("name", "blah") 
field1.text = "some value1" 
field2 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field2") 
field2.set("name", "asdfasd") 
field2.text = "some vlaue2" 
tree = ET.ElementTree(root) 
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

Output:

```
<root>
   <doc>
        <field1 name="blah">some value1</field1>
        <field2 name="asdfasd">some vlaue2</field2>
   </doc>
</root>
```

For differences between the two solutions, `lxml.etree` and `ElementTree`, have a look at this doc [lxml.etree versus ElementTree](http://lxml.de/1.3/compatibility.html).

`cElementTree` is slightly faster compared to `lxml.etree`, anyway the latter is still a fast xml parser written in C, and I think the difference is negligible (benchmarks [here](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm#benchmarks)).

Comment: If you want to thank me even more, upvote my answer :) have a good day! ;)